# Combining many rake tasks into one rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, task

Instead of running each rake task individually like this:

```
rake db:drop
rake db:create
rake db:migrate
rake db:load
```

I want to run one rake task that does all for.

This is what I have for my rakefile:

```
desc 'This rebuilds development db'
namespace :rebuild_dev do
 Rake::Task["db:drop"].execute
 Rake::Task["db:create"].execute
 Rake::Task["db:migrate"].execute
 Rake::Task["db:load"].execute
end
```

The above doesn't work when I run it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You want `invoke` not `execute`. A little excerpt from my own code showing how to pass variables:

```
namespace :clients do

  task :create, [:client] => ["clients:creation:checks"] do |t, args|
    Rake::Task["clients:creation:git"].invoke(client, password)
    Rake::Task["server:virtualhost:create"].invoke(client)
    Rake::Task["server:virtualhost:enable"].invoke(client)
    Rake::Task["server:reload"].invoke
    Rake::Task["db:roles:create"].invoke(client, password)
    Rake::Task["db:create"].invoke(client, client)
    Rake::Task["db:migrate"].invoke(client)
  end

end
```

Alternatively, you can make the task depend upon another task as I have done above with `:create` depending upon `clients:creation:checks`.

Just to clarify, a namespace is for grouping tasks, so you must actually define the tasks within the namespace as I have above. You can't simply call tasks from within a namespace.

So your code above should be:

```
desc 'This rebuilds development db'
task :rebuild_dev do
  Rake::Task["db:drop"].invoke
  Rake::Task["db:create"].invoke
  Rake::Task["db:migrate"].invoke
  Rake::Task["db:load"].invoke
end
```

Comment: why `invoke`, can I use `execute` means `execute(client)`

Comment: @AMICMING - `execute` will run only the task while `invoke` will run any dependencies. Additionally, it will only run the task if needed. 
*Note: This was the case 8 years ago; I honestly don't know if it has changed since then.* http://chrisroos.co.uk/blog/2007-12-06-ruby-rake-invoke-vs-execute

Comment: @Topher Fangio, Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 68):

You can do it with dependencies on a task with no body.

```
desc 'This rebuilds development db'
task :rebuild_dev => ["db:drop", "db:create", "db:migrate", "db:load"]
```

Comment: How would this work when passing in params to the sub tasks?

Answer (score 3):

```
namespace :rebuild_dev do
 desc 'This rebuilds development db'
  task :clean_slate => :environment do 
    Rake::Task["db:drop"].invoke
    Rake::Task["db:create"].invoke
    Rake::Task["db:migrate"].invoke
    Rake::Task["db:load"].invoke
  end
end
```